# Pandas merge two dataframes based on list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two pandas dataframes

```
   category      price                                Submodel                                   Variant Model    Year                 Engine     Make
0    131090  AU $26.80  DC_ Hatchback 2.0 16V (DCRFNC, DCRFNF)   FWD Petrol 2.0L 4cyl 100kW RFN (EW10J4)    C5  2004.0  1997cc 100kW (Petrol)  Citroën
1    131090  AU $26.80  DC_ Hatchback 2.0 HDi (DCRHZB, DCRHZE)  FWD Diesel 2.0L 4cyl 80kW RHZ (DW10ATED)    C5  2004.0   1997cc 80kW (Diesel)  Citroën
2    131090  AU $26.80   DC_ Hatchback 3.0 V6 (DCXFXC, DCXFXF)   FWD Petrol 3.0L 6cyl 152kW XFX (ES9J4S)    C5  2004.0  2946cc 152kW (Petrol)  Citroën
```

and

```
        ePID        Make   Model  Year                                          Submodel                                         Variant                 Engine        Body         Type  Ktype
0  127467791  Alfa Romeo     159  2011  939 Sportwagon 1.9 JTDM 16V (939BXC1B, 939BXC12)           FWD Diesel 1.9L 4cyl 110kW 939 A2.000  1910cc 110kW (Diesel)  Sportwagon     JTDM 16V  19449
1  127467811     Citroën  Xantia  1995                       X1_,X2_ Hatchback 2.0 Turbo       FWD Petrol 2.0L 4cyl 108kW RGX (XU10J2TE)  1998cc 108kW (Petrol)   Hatchback        Turbo   5140
2  127467831         BMW      X6  2008                           E71,E72 SAC xDrive 35 i  AWD Petrol 3.0L 6cyl 225kW N55 B30 A,N54 B30 A  2979cc 225kW (Petrol)         SAC  xDrive 35 i  31004
```

What I want is to join two dataframes based on list of columns i-e `['Make', 'Model', 'Year']`.
I want to merge to dataframes based on above mentioned columns and save all columns.

The main thing here is that in full dataset not all columns match so I want to match maximum number of columns. It doesn't need to match all those columns. It can match even a single column and add another column named `cols_count` saving the number of columns matched.

Comment: All examples are here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: @GedasMiksenas Thanks for the help but I didn't find any related helpful example.